# Select some columns from CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a CSV file, which includes 100 rows (as cases) and 1100 columns (as features)
(There is 1100 features for each case).

I want to use the 20 columns (say 55-74) and visualize it instead of 1100 columns. How can I select these data (100 x 20) and use it in my code?

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client side?  Where is the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, this could be done...

You could use the accessor function to create output data that only contains your specified range of 20 columns:

```
d3.csv('path/to/your/file.csv')
  // this is run once for each row of your data
  .row(function accessor(d) {
    // make an array of all the keys (1100 of them)
    var keys = d3.map(d).keys();
    // create an empty object
    var outputDatum = {};
    // fill it with the key/value pairs from indexes 55 - 74
    for (var i = 55; i < 75; i++) {
      outputDatum[keys[i]] = d[keys[i]];
    }
    // return the object you built
    return outputDatum;
  })
  // this is the callback that runs when the data is ready
  .get(function callback(error, data) {
    // use the data to make something
  });
```

The problem is, without knowing what the names of these keys are in advance, they probably aren't going to be of much use to you. Also, what kind of values are stored in these mysterious 20 columns? Are they all the same type, even?

You can technically still use these values, for example:

```
function callback(error, data) {
  d3.selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('div')
    .text(function(d) { return d3.values(d)[6]; }
}
```

This would create divs containing the values in the 7th column for each row...except not exactly, because object key/value pairs are not stored or retrieved in a defined order.

You may need to rethink the structure of your data. If the index of the columns is of more relevance than their names, then they should probably be your rows instead.

---

**update**

If you know the labels of the columns you are interested in, that makes it a much simpler problem. You could then use your accessor function to output your chosen data like this:

```
d3.csv('path/to/your/file.csv')
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.featureX,
      y: d.featureY,
      z: d.featureZ
    };
  })
  .get(function(e, data) {
    d3.selectAll('div')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('div')
      .text(function(d) { return d.x; });
  });
```

This time, the accessor function gives you back data with properties `x`, `y`, and `z` representing the original data that was called (for this example) `featureX`, `featureY`, and `featureZ`. This example would then create a div for each row's featureX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Actually, what I have is a bunch of data, but I am just interested in some of the features of the cases (I mean all rows, but some columns).
I think your code is helpful for me. 
If I want to select some of the columns using their labels what should I do?
I tried something like thi, but it did not work:
key == "label1" || key == "label2" || key == "label3"

Comment: Also, I tried the code you provided. The console complains that :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined
What is the problem?

Comment: I've edited the answer. In the `.row()` function, `d.featureX` represents the column labeled `featureX` in your original data. It outputs an object with a property `x`, which can later be accessed as `d.x` when assigning an attribute. x, y, and z are of course completely arbitrary, you can assign whatever labels you want.

Comment: Are you sure the d3 library loaded properly? d3.csv().row should always be defined, even if the file doesn't exist at the specified path...

Comment: Yes, I have it :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>My Project</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8">   </script>
  </head>

Comment: You need to add `http://` to the url. It should be `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">`

Comment: I have the [http://]. Here, it did not display.
Again, it is complaining about row!

Comment: Okay, I solved the row problem.

Comment: Add three lines at the top of your script. `console.log('d3 is', typeof d3);` then `console.log('d3.csv is', typeof d3.csv);` then `console.log('d3.csv().row is', typeof d3.csv().row);`. Let me know what the output says.

Comment: Now, it is working and the output is:
`d3 is object test.html/
d3.csv is function test.html/
d3.csv().row is function`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used your updated code, and it works fine for some of the data. However, for the other data which are float numbers or E-notation format data (such as 2.99283E-05), it does not work. For example, if data[0] is like : [42, 603.45]; The output for `consol.log(data[0])` is  : 
`Object {featureX: "42", featureY: undefined}` 
If I use `y: +d.featureY` or `y: Number(d.featureY)`, "undefined" changes to 'NaN'.
Do you have any suggestion that how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If your value is `undefined`, then trying to convert it to a number will give you `NaN`. I think at this point, if you're still having trouble you should create a new question with specific details about your present issue, rather than continuing this thread. I'll be happy to assist you there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem has been solved, totally!!! Yay!!